# Is it wrong to say a serial killer “assassinated” a victim?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Assassin: *“1.) **a murderer**, especially one who kills a politically prominent person for fanatical or monetary reasons.”*
(via - http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/assassin?s=t)

Emphasis mine ^.

- “He assassinated his fourth victim on stage from afar with a rifle shot.”
- “He assassinated his fourth victim on stage up close with a pistol.”
- “He assassinated his fourth victim behind stage with a garrote.”

I realize *“killed”*, or *“murdered”* might be preferable by some, or completely re-written, but are the above sentences otherwise improper in regards to the use of *assassination*?

Comment: Given the usual connotation of "assassination," your readers will be puzzled unless the fourth victim is a public figure.  Not to mention why it took three attempts with three different methods to kill him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "politically prominent figure" part is strongly bound to the meaning of "assassinate" in common usage (in AmE).  So no, I wouldn't use "assassinated" in your examples, unless the victim(s?) were politically prominent individuals.

Comment: Assassination does not require political motivation. It could be criminal figures. It could be vengeance. Or financial. A serial contract killer can indeed, and in fact do indeed, engage in serial assassination. Have you never read of professional serial assassins of the cartels in Mexico.

Comment: I didn't say it was wrong to use "assassinate". I said it was "common usage" to use it in he political sense, and that I wouldn't use it in his example. Anyway, it means hashish smokers, who, in my experience, wouldn't make good assassins anyway; the badmouthing of hashish users has apparently gone on for centuries. And even Donovan, a fairly hip dude, referred to  a "violent hash smoker" who "shook a chocolate machine".  http://www.metrolyrics.com/sunny-goodge-street-lyrics-donovan.html   Not a killer, but "violent" to property.

Comment: The word *assassin* is Arabic origin. If I remember somewhat, due to the Ismaili branch of shia islam, which started off as a ninja-esque group, due to the name of their leader (can't remember what). Nothing to do with smoking anything.

Comment: @BlessedGeek from Arabic hashishiyyin "hashish-users" http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=assassin, shaik-al-jibal was "ninja-esque" smoker.